# Is anyone actively developing software to be used with the Emotiv headset?

Tags: user-interface, mind-mapping

Based on the "featured apps" section of the main page
http://www.emotiv.com/index.php

Alot of the so called "mind control" apps so far seem to be fairly rudimentary read/scan apps that look to profile a certain activity, or perhaps allow the user to manipulate or control an app in a way loosely analogous to using a mouse/keyboard.

I'm just wondering if anyone is currently working on something (assuming they can talk about it) that is a mind blowingly spectacular use of the Emotiv headset?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. have a look.  The software shown in this video will be out shortly as soon as testing and refining is finished.  It's called EmoLens and it uses the Emotiv EPOC headset to detect emotions and tag Flickr photographs with them.  Note the emotions shown being detected in the video (Happy/Sad/Anger/Fear) have been changed to (Interesting/Happy/Funny):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9_XZlHoSp0

I'm the author.

- roschler